# How to blur image's edges after clip on winPhone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have clipped Image:

```
<Image Name="Img" Source="/UntitledImage.jpg">
  <Image.Clip>
    <EllipseGeometry Center="115,115" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"></EllipseGeometry>
  </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

or:

```
<Image Name="oldImg" Source="/UntitledImage.jpg">
  <Image.Clip>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="115,115,50,50"></RectangleGeometry>
  </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

I want added blur for each edge for Image after clip.
I want manage thick blur area for Image.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a blurred version of each image, why not put a semi-transparent image over the top of the image to give the appearance of a blurred edge instead?

This would, I expect, be much quicker and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might be a little heavier for your purpose, but I suppose it will serve any need you could have.

You can try to use [Nokia Imaging SDK](https://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/nokia_apis/imaging.xhtml) to process your images. The SDK usage is very simple and well documented [In the developer library](https://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk.html).

Also, before you decide, the link above contains sample apps to explore the effects.